# UITableViewCellでdetailTextLabelが表示されない

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

SwiftにてUITableViewCellを使用しているのですが、detailTextLabelに格納したデータが表示されません。表示させる方法を教えていただきたいです。何か書き方が誤っているのでしょうか？

```
//データ
var dataInSection = [["男性","女性"],["誕生日","都道府県"]]
//セクション
var sectionIndex:[String] = ["",""]
//データを返す
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var test = dataInSection[indexPath.section]
        if self.appDelegate.sex == 1 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }else{
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = test[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var test = dataInSection[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = test[indexPath.row]
        // 詳細テキストラベル
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "test"
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
}
```

現状の表示結果は下記のとおりです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `UITableViewCell`のスタイルはどのように指定されておられますか? スタイルが指定できるような方法でセルをインスタンス化しないと、`detailTextLabel`が表示されない`.default`スタイルが適用されます。

Comment: OOPer様ご連絡ありがとうございます。スタイル設定を確認したところ、「Custom」が選択されておりましたので、「Right Detail」に変更したところ、表示されました。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: Storyboardにprototype cellを配置していた、と言うことでしょうか。できればその辺りはご質問本文中に明記していただきたかったところです。なお、あなたのコード中に2箇所ずつある`as IndexPath`と`as UITableViewCell`は不要ですので削除してしまった方が良いでしょう。コメントの内容が解決のヒントになったというのは嬉しいのですが、コメントはコメントでしかありませんので、できればご自身でお時間を取って解決方法を回答の形でご投稿(及び承認…)くださるようお願いします。

Comment: OOper様、投稿内容の情報が不足しており申し訳ございませんでした。ご丁寧にご回答いただき誠にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboardにprototype cellを配置しており、style設定に「Custom」が設定されておりましたので、表示されておりませんでした。
Storyboard上でstyle設定を「Ri‌​ght Detail」に変更したところ、うまくdetailTextLabelに格納したデータが表示されるようになりました。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]